# Looking for easy way to analyze var_dump (PHP) on large objects

Tags: php, debugging, var-dump

I know (PHP's) var_dump is supposed to be "human readable" and all, but analyzing large objects is just a pain in the neck. I am struggling to make sense of a few of the large objects that are being passed around in a script that we are running.  (I know that using xdebug with and IDE is a good idea, but I have not been able to get xdebug to run on this project for some reason - several days lost, ugh).

Any ideas on how I can easily digest the contents of a really big var_dump?  Any ideas are welcome... Although I am hoping that there is something similar to [Thomas Frank's JSON tool](http://www.thomasfrank.se/downloadableJS/JSONeditor_example.html) (where you just put some code in and it gives a nice graphical representation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141585/a-more-pretty-informative-var-dump-alternative-in-php/13597915#13597915 here is a similar post with a couple good suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a look at [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/). It enables you to write information to the firebug-console. If you write an array or object to the log and hover with your mouse over it, you get a nice presentation of the contents of that array. Here is a screenshot of a simple [example](http://www.laurent-laville.org/pear/pepr/Log_FirePHP/Log_FirePHP_example1.png).

Comment: Looks like I already had FirePHP integrated in my project, so I used it. Very useful.  It does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

I'd just use [dBug](http://dbug.ospinto.com/).

Comment: I was going to suggest dBug too. I include it in every project I make now, I can't imagine working without it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  dBug looks really nice var_dump replacement.  I must say that FirePHP seems a little more convenient since it doesn't muck up the entire webpage you are trying to debug. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I made a var_dump alternative you should like:

http://raveren.github.io/kint/

Screenshot demonstrating content-aware features:

[image: Kint screenshot]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://raveren.github.io/kint/img/features-content-aware.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I'd make my own var_dump() equivalent based on some recursive function. With some parameters (such as nesting level, certain element name, etc) to pass it could be quite useful I think.